# 'SnowflakeCursor' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to execute a select * query on snowflake using snowflake connector for python and while trying to add response data to a list getting following error :  'SnowflakeCursor' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

This is my source code

```
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
            user=****,
            password=****,
            account=****,
            warehouse=****,
            host=****
        )
cmd = conn.cursor()
        for i in self.queries:
                cmd.execute(i['query'])
                data_sets.append(list(cmd.to_dict()))

        return data_sets
```

Getting the exception while doing cmd.to_dict(). Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Calling `to_dict` on `cmd` (which is a cursor object) doesn't seem to make a lot of sense -- you'd probably want to use the `cmd.fetchall()` to return the query's results as a list, and then cast the list elements to dictionaries.

There is probably an easier approach, however, and it's in using the [`DictCursor` variant of `cursor`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-dictcursor-to-fetch-values-by-column-name) (which represents rows as dicts, rather than as tuples).

Here's how your modified code would look:

```
from snowflake.connector import DictCursor

cmd = conn.cursor(DictCursor)
        for i in self.queries:
                cmd.execute(i['query'])
                data_sets.append(cmd.fetchall())
```

Comment: This should have a green check next to it

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. This just saved me from having to write a bunch of custom code. This should be prominent in the Snowflake fetch all() documentation.